# Angular date format international

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, angular-date-format

I need to format "item.value.date" as dd/MM/yyyy on a "date.component.html" regardless of the international settings on the local machine. The code below does work on Angular 2, but does not on Angular 4: some dates are wrong.
Request: I need a solution for Angular 4 (npm v5.3.0; node v6.11.2)

```
 <tbody *ngIf="Result" 
 <template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="Result"> 
     <td {item.value.date  | date:Format}}</td>  
 </template> 
 </tbody>
```

On "date.component.ts":

```
 get Format(): string { 
 return "dd/MM/yyyy "; 
 }
```

On "app.module.ts":

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core'; // for LOCALE_ID
@NgModule({   declarations: [DateComponent],   
imports: [BrowserModule,FormsModule],   
providers: [ { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "en-US" } ] }) 
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a custom format method which doesn't need to read locals:

**HTML:**

```
   <td {{myFormat(item.value.date)}}</td>
```

**Typescript**:

```
   myFormat(date): string { 
      return ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2)+ "/" + ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + date.getFullYear()
   }
```

Comment: Dear @Vega, thank you. It is not clear how to manage "date" variabile. I tried using an input parameter "date" in "date.component.ts": Format(date: Date): string { <your code> }. In "date.component.html" I wrote:  <td {item.value.date  | date:Format(item.value.date) }}</td>. It does not work. Please advise.

Comment: On compile time it works, but on Runtime it throw an error on DateComponent.html: "TypeError: date.getDay is not a function". Should I import a package?

Comment: I use npm v5.3.0, node v6.11.2. I confirm on Runtime it throws an error on DateComponent.html. "ERROR TypeError: date.getFullYear is not a function". Same using only date.getDate and date.getMonth. I even tried local variable:  `dateTemp: Date; 
 dayTemp: number; 

 myFormat(date): string {
  this.dateTemp = new Date("02-09-1980");
  this.dayTemp = date.getFullYear();
  return "02-09-1980";
}`

Comment: What is the format of   item.value.date ? is it string or date?

Comment: Also try myFormat(olddate): string { 
    let date = new Date()
    return ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2)+ "/" + ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + date.getFullYear()
}

Comment: Vega: item.value.date is "Date". Using IntelliSense I got getFullYear()

Comment: How about the test above?

Comment: This code works: `myFormat(olddate): string { 
   let date = new Date();
   return ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2)+ "/" + ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
  }` but if I try to use olddate parameter, it does not even though I declared it as Date

Comment: log its value and its type again to check please

Comment: olddate and so item.value.date are not in date format. What's in result? {{result | json}}

Comment: Dear Vega, log: "olddate:  01/10/1935 00:00:00 typeof(olddate):  string". I checked the "Result" array: "date" value is a Date, but it gets value from webapi using string (date: "01/10/1935 00:00:00"). I cannot change webapi, thus I have to manage the date as string. Kindly ask for advice.

Comment: If I get you right, and if olddate type is string and it has  'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss' format, then you can just keep the dd/mm/yyyy part by doing myFormat(date): string { 
      return date.substrig(0, 10 )
   }

Comment: I cannot make it because it is not sure that the format is always "dd/MM/yyyy". It could change depending on the settings of the local user machine. I need a solutions that is indipendent. In Angular 2 it is used: "providers: [ { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "en-US" } ] })"  on "app.module.ts". Maybe I need something similar for Angular 4.

Comment: Dera Vega, if I cannot use the pipe in Angular 4 (npm v5.3.0; node v6.11.2), I wonder if it is a workaround. I have to bind the array on a the form on the page.

Comment: @Pipe({
  name: 'dateFormat'
})
export class DateFormat {
  transform(date, args) {
    return new Date(date);
  }
}

Comment: Could you provide a sample of  Result, please?

Comment: Dear Vega, sorry for my delay:     `"Result" = [
        value: {
            "surname": "Black",
            "name": "John",
            "gender": "M",
            "date": "01/10/1935 00:00:00",
        }
    ]`

Comment: @David, I am a little confused with the Date format. I set up a demo, please take a look. It takes date as string. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gapyvu?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Vega: thank you for your demo! Tomorrow morning I will try it. I expect that statement `date = new Date(resultDate);` does not work if the format date in the string variable `resultDate` changes: e.g. dd/MM/yyyy or MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: Dear Vega, using exactly your code, here is the log in FormatDate function: it work using MM/dd/yyy: _formatDate resultDate:  01/10/1935 00:00:00 date:  Thu Jan 10 1935 00:00:00 GMT+0100 
formatDate resultDate:  18/01/1961 00:00:00 date:  Invalid Date
formatDate resultDate:  03/01/1945 00:00:00 date:  Thu Mar 01 1945 00:00:00 GMT+0100 
formatDate resultDate:  29/11/1935 00:00:00 date:  Invalid Date
formatDate resultDate:  21/07/1961 00:00:00 date:  Invalid Date

Comment: result.value.date:  01/10/1935 00:00:00
result.value.date:  18/01/1961 00:00:00
result.value.date:  03/01/1945 00:00:00
result.value.date:  29/11/1935 00:00:00
result.value.date:  21/07/1961 00:00:00
result.value.date:  05/03/1964 00:00:00
result.value.date:  05/09/1972 00:00:00
result.value.date:  02/03/1951 00:00:00
result.value.date:  20/09/1936 00:00:00
result.value.date:  12/07/1956 00:00:00
result.value.date:  15/09/1957 00:00:00
result.value.date:  12/07/1958 00:00:00

Comment: You have set console.log(resultDate) inside formatDate() method? From your comment I am not sure if it's an error log?

Comment: Do you get Results from an API? Did you write it or you receive it as is? It seems to me that maybe there are incoherences on dat type, sometimes is's string, sometime it's date

Comment: I did set `console.log(resultDate)` inside formatDate() method in the component, for sure! I get Result from a WebAPI that I cannot change: I do receive it as is: it a _string_ for sure! I have to manage it depending on international settings on the local machine, binding the data on a table

Comment: Okay, thanks for the precisions :) So for some values, it doesn't work, I understand. Could you make an exert of Result for the values that cause the error?

Comment: `resultDate:  18/01/1961 00:00:00 date:  Invalid Date
resultDate:  03/01/1945 00:00:00 date:  Thu Mar 01 1945 00:00:00 GMT+0100 
resultDate:  29/11/1935 00:00:00 date:  Invalid Date
resultDate:  21/07/1961 00:00:00 date:  Invalid Date
resultDate:  05/03/1964 00:00:00 date:  Sun May 03 1964 00:00:00 GMT+0200 
resultDate:  05/09/1972 00:00:00 date:  Tue May 09 1972 00:00:00 GMT+0200 
resultDate:  20/09/1936 00:00:00 date:  Invalid Date
resultDate:  15/09/1957 00:00:00 date:  Invalid Date
resultDate:  15/01/1966 00:00:00 date:  Invalid Date`

Comment: I am lost, I don't why it wouldn't work. I updated my demo with some of the 'invalid' dates from your exert and they all work. Check please:  stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gapyvu?file=app%2Fapp.component.‌​ts

Comment: I think that it could depend on the international settings on the specific machine. Is it possible? The string variable "resultDate" seems in "MM/dd/yyyy" format. When "MM" format part is more then 12, it breaks.

Comment: Look the date for "Jane Smith" in the demo, it's "12/31/1980" and it works. But remove { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "en-US" } from app.module to test if that helps